# problem: Visualization shape showing up on Visualization shape in python

Tags: python, algorithm, data-science, data-mining

I am working on showing a correlation matrix for dataset features using this code

```
#Correlation matrix/Heatmap
fig= plt.subplots(figsize=(14,8))  
sns.heatmap(cdf.corr() , annot = True, vmin=-1, vmax=1, center= 0)
```

and then show the distribution of two features on the grid with

```
plt.plot(cdf['BALANCE'], cdf['PAYMENTS'], marker='.', linewidth=0, color='#128128') 
plt.grid(which='major', color='#cccccc', alpha=0.45) 
plt.xlabel('Balance', fontsize=16) 
plt.ylabel('Payment', fontsize=16) 
plt.title('Balance vs payment', fontsize=20) 
plt.show()
```

But the problem here is that the correlation matrix is displayed in combination with the other shape, what is the reason for that?

Like this:
[image: mixing the grid with correlation matrix in the one shape]

Comment: Can you show us what is exact problem is? I don't think it is very clear from the text.

Comment: Hi @Grayrigel ,I added pictures explaining the matter in the original post, which you can view

Answer (score 0):

The two plots are drawn on the same axes. You can either clear the axis with `plt.cla()` after the heatmap or have different axes (either both in the same figure of different ones)

for different figures

```
fig1 , ax1 = plt.subplots()
fig2 , ax2 = plt.subplots()
sns.heatmap(cdf.corr(), ax = ax1 )
ax2.plot( cdf['BALANCE'], cdf['PAYMENTS'] )
plt.show()
```

or on the same figure

```
fig , axs = plt.subplots(2)
sns.heatmap( cdf.corr() , ax = axs[0] )
axs[1].plot( cdf['BALANCE'], cdf['PAYMENTS'] )
plt.show()
```